# Priority queu mass transit azure service bus

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there a possibility to use priority queues on Azure Service Bus with MassTransit? I searched in the documentation but I have not found an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, No.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/priority-queue

"Microsoft Azure doesn't provide a queuing mechanism that natively supports automatic prioritization of messages through sorting. However, it does provide Azure Service Bus topics and subscriptions that support a queuing mechanism that provides message filtering, together with a wide range of flexible capabilities that make it ideal for use in most priority queue implementations."